# An error occured with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I started a new project in Java web services in NetBeans with Tomcat 5.5 as server. When I try to run I got this error

```
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file:/C:/Users/sadesh/AppData/Local/Temp/context46924.xml&war=file:/C:/Users/sadesh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TambramBuzz/build/web/
FAIL - Invalid context path null was specified
Deployment error:
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
        at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:163)
        at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:104)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:460)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:151)
Caused by: The module has not been deployed.
        at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:157)
        ... 16 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How can I resolve it?

The server log says

> SEVERE: Error starting static
>   Resources
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Document base
>   C:\Users\sadesh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cssjquery\build\web
>   does not exist or is not a readable
>   directory
>           at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:3855)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4024)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error:

> FAIL - Invalid context path null was specified Deployment error: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

So what does the server log say?